# Trying to get a list element by index in prolog

Tags: prolog

This is what I have so far:

```
getByIndex([X],0,E):- E is X.
getByIndex([H|_],0,E):- E is H.
getByIndex([_|T],I,E) :- getByIndex(T,I-1,E).
```

It seems to work when requesting the first element, but not subsequent elements, and I can't quite figure out why.

I'm aware that there might be a built-in solution in something like SWI-prolog, but I'd like to understand why this fails.

Comment: The first two rules express the same relationship. Also operators is and = are very different, look it up. In the third rule, you are trying to put an expression I-1 where it’s not allowed, also you don’t account for the situation where I is negative.

Comment: Nitpick: the expression is allowed there, it just means something else.

Comment: I see this all the time from beginners.... DO NOT use `is/2` like an assignment operator. It is specifically for *arithmetic expression evaluation*. If `X` happens to be a number, then `E is X` will happen to work. But is assumes `X` is a numeric expression. Use unification. Either `getByIndex([X],0,E):- E = X`. or better yet, `getByIndex([X],0,X).` Also, and somewhat related, Prolog does not evaluate terms such as `I-1` as an arithmetic expression in line. To Prolog, it's just a term unless you explicitly request its evaluation with `is/2` or other evaluating operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getByIndex([X], 0, X).
getByIndex([H|_], 0, H).
getByIndex([_|T], I, E) :- NewIndex is I-1, getByIndex(T, NewIndex, E).
```

Two things: "E is X" is not the same as "E=X". is/2 is used to evaluate a mathematical expression, while =/2 is unification.

Secondly, when you are using I-1 in getByIndex(T,I-1,E), the second argument is being unified with I-1, which means that X is literally "I-1". To avoid that you should create a temporary variable NewIndex, and use is/2 to calculate I-1.